# Omnia latch set rose cover removal

Tags: doors, latches

I called Omnia and they sent me the rose cover washer installation tool. The problem is that the tool doesn’t fit inside the threaded washer. I called Omnia back and they said they only have the one size. Someone suggested using a nickel. It fits but does not catch the small notches in the threaded washer.

As for instructions, written ones don’t show you how to do anything relating to the rose cover. Omnia does have a YouTube channel which also doesn’t address this problem.
I have packages and invoices from the previous owner that show this is an Omnia product. However, it’s for a dummy lever not a latch set. The one in question is brass lever style 235 non-locking (passage function only). I don’t have an exact model number form the manufacturer.

I also tried rotating the rose,but both sides are attached by an internal screw that you cannot access without first removing the washer.

It seems they only way to remove the rose cover is to remove the threaded washer shown in the picture. I tried to attach more pics, but unable to do so.

How do I remove this latch set without damaging it? Or more specifically, how do I use the tool provided by Omnia even though it doesn’t seem to fit?

Pic of door knob with handles removed.
[image: pic of door knob with handles removed]

Comment: Ask them for more explicit directions or a video showing how the tool fits with your particular model of... what is this that you're working on?

Comment: I think this is a doorknob, but a pic of the tool and where it's supposed to go would be extremely helpful.

Comment: Silly question perhaps, but if Omnia says they only have this one tool and it doesn't fit, are you sure it's an Omnia doorknob?

Comment: Not familiar with that brand. What do the edge of the door, and the other side, look like? Does the whole rose just unscrew if rotated counterclockwise?

Comment: It appears that you've now created two accounts and that's why you couldn't edit your original question. Please follow the [instructions here](https://diy.stackexchange.com/help/merging-accounts) to get the accounts merged. Return to the original browser/device and the cookies should still be there to allow you to make the edit.

Comment: Do the packages or invoices show the Omnia model number? Please edit this information in.

Comment: Links to the instructions & instructional video might be helpful. If you can't post multiple images, upload them to imgur.com and post the link to that. Someone will probably embed them for you, but at least they'll be available.